# React setState : unable to update state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to understand why setState in this case is not able to update state object. Below is a simple example of my issue.

```js
class Temp extends Component<TempProps, TempState> {
  constructor(props: TempProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 1: "apple", 2: "banana", 3: "pineapple" };
  }
 
  onBtnClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => {
        const newState = { ...prevState };
        delete newState["2"];
        console.log(newState); //{ 1: "apple", 3: "pineapple" }
        console.log(newState === prevState); //false
        return newState;
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state); //{ 1: "apple", 2: "banana", 3: "pineapple" }
      }
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onBtnClick}>click me</button>
    );
  }
}
export default Temp;
```

Why setState() in onBtnClick() is not able to update the state object, even though prevState===newState is false?
I'm so confused... thanks a lot for the comments!

Comment: As an aside `console.log(newState === prevState)` will always return false; they're two different objects.

Comment: Your code should work. Can you provide a snippet/sandbox that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `this.setState()` performs a merge of current state and supplied value. So that the new state is like this `newState = { ...oldState, ...suppliedValue }`. This means that any properties omitted in the new argument will be left unchanged. That's why you could call `setState({ b: 22 })` on a state currently having `{ a: 11, b: 12 }` and the new state would be a merge of the supplied value and old value: `{a: 11, b: 22}`. The fact that you omitted the property: a in the supplied value won't delete it from the final state.

So the only workarounds that I know of are:

1. Assign a nullish value to the property you want to delete, like `null` or `undefined`. This is ugly, but might serve for your needs. For eg, `this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, b: undefined }))`
2. Don't assign your app's state directly to this.setState but to a nested property. Something like:

```
. . .
constructor(props: TempProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { appState: { 1: "apple", 2: "banana", 3: "pineapple" } };
  }

. . .

onBtnClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => {
        const newState = { ...(prevState.appState) };
        delete newState["2"];
        console.log(newState); //{ 1: "apple", 3: "pineapple" }
        console.log(newState === prevState); //false
        return { appState: newState };
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state); //{ 1: "apple", 3: "pineapple" }
      }
    );
  };
. . .
```

Comment: awesome! super clear explanation, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two object like this.

```
JSON.stringify(Object A) === JSON.stringify(Object B)
```